# Cannot add project or tag to my task in taskwarrior

Tags: terminal, taskwarrior

Everytime when I try to add project to taskwarrior in terminal (`task 1 project:organize`), I get this message: `No command specified - assuming 'information'.
No matches.`

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must to write 'modify' after task number:

> task 1 modify project:organize